# Looking to create a Voice Recognition to Text using Java

Tags: java, eclipse, voice-recognition, sphinx4

I'm not sure how to ask this...but! I'm working on a voice recognition project. The app would be built as a phone bot... so scripted questions with yes or no replays.Ever thing shows as text in console.

Q: So I know sphinx-4 has a good library but how do I install and use it?

F.Y.I
* Java
* Eclipse
* Using A Mac
-Any advice would help, sorry if my question was a bit vague!

Comment: Read the documentation

Comment: Try downloading the jar files from [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search). 
Follow the instructions [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4).

Comment: Thanks for the links Ayush. And every one else, I'll get back with you on what works for me!

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Comment: No I haven't solved it yet